# Strange Problems with Connect4 AI

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been working on a Connect 4 Robot Project, for which purpose I am trying to get [this](https://github.com/Gimu/connect-four-js/tree/master/plain/alphabeta/js) code to work on my PC with node.js, so that it can be run on a Raspberry Pi, with sensors and some buttons being the only input.
Unfortunately I am not very experienced with Javascript, which is why I am having some issues with it.
I commented out most of the lines that were incompatible with node.js, and I managed to get it to work for one round.
However, as soon as I call the "act" function more than once:

```
Game.prototype.act = function(column  /*e*/) {

    // Human round
    if (that.round == 0) that.place(column    /*element.cellIndex*/);

    // Computer round
    if (that.round == 1) that.generateComputerDecision();
}
Game.prototype.place = function(column) {
    // If not finished
    if (that.board.score() != that.score && that.board.score() != -that.score && !that.board.isFull()) {
    if (!that.board.place(column)) {              //Place coin in seperate Board class
        return alert("Invalid move!");
    }

    that.round = that.switchRound(that.round);
    that.updateStatus();
}
}
```

things start getting weird. When I for example test it with "act(1)", immediately followed by "act(2)", the second coin comes out in the wrong column.
I did some more testing with console logs and it appears that the programm does not run in the order that I want. It seems to start the next "act" function call before the last one has finished calculating the Computers move.

How can I solve this?

Comment: To start with you can take `Game.prototype.place` out of `Game.prototype.act` as it's currently in there but might just be an error made when posting on here.

Comment: Oh yeah i see, yes that was just an error while posting, thanks for pointing it out